# Multiply with XML in FLEX

Tags: apache-flex

I write a code which is return the following XML which contain in a string type variable.

```
<imageedit>
  <matrix a="0.5213903738845257" b="0" c="0" d="0.5213903738845257" tx="559.6" ty="1.0784769629138395"/>
  <cutout x="0" y="0" width="400" height="568"/>
</imageedit>
```

Now i want to multiply all the nodes with 3 and again store in that string type variable. how can i do this?

Comment: do you mean replicate the tags three times or multiply the values of a, b, c, tx, ty, x, y, width and height by 3?

Comment: yes i mean exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use E4X to access attributes like this:

```
var xml : XML = <imageedit>
  <matrix a="0.5213903738845257" b="0" c="0" d="0.5213903738845257" tx="559.6" ty="1.0784769629138395"/>
  <cutout x="0" y="0" width="400" height="568"/>
</imageedit>

xml.matrix.@a = Number(xml.matrix.@a)*3
```

and the same for other attributes. You can also iterate through them with 'for each'.